# Hive Subquery in SELECT

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, subquery, hql

I have a query like

```
SELECT name, salary/ (SELECT max(money) from table_sal) FROM table_a;
```

I get an error saying

```
Unsupported SubQuery Expression Invalid subquery. Subquery in SELECT could only be top-level expression
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work with a `CROSS JOIN`?

```
SELECT name, salary / s.max_money
FROM table_a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT max(money) as max_money from table_sal) s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as below, please let me know if it works for you.

```
 Select t1.name
      , t1.salary/T2.max_money
 from
   (SELECT name
         , salary, 1 as dummy
           from  table_a ) t1 
  Join
      (SELECT max(money) as max_money
            , 1 as dummy 
              from table_sal) t2
  on t1.dummy = t2.dummy ;
```

Comment: Inconsistent layout break my eyes, sorry, I felt the urge to 'tidy' it up.